# How to use project my screen app for two phones?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, lumia

I want to open project my screen for two phones connected to a single PC. 
When I try to open a new window ( when one window of project my screen already exists ) it is showing [image].

Is it possible to connect two phones and open the app simultaneously without disconnecting the other ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to using a [Windows Phone](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com), and not developing software for them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to connect two devices and project your screen of both the devices.

I think this is somehow connected to deploying application packages to the phone. When I tried to connect two phones and deploy my application package I have got the following error message:

> Error 204 Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Connecting to the device': 
>   SmartDeviceException - App deployment to the Windows Phone failed because multiple Windows Phone devices were detected. You should only connect one phone.  Sofascore.WP